# Meteor Autoform Select2 add on the fly

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, on-the-fly, jquery-select2

I want to be able to add a tag on the fly to a tags collection, using autoform and select2, similar to this example from select2.
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags
I have already created a tags collection which I can add to it from it's dedicated form. The enduser must be able to select available tags and be able to add a new tag if not available in the global form without going to the dedicated tags form. Is there some server based hook for autoform I can attach to or something to achieve this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `tags` option.

There is an example here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-select2#setting-select2-options